# ReactJS : Moderate severity vulnerabilities while running npm react-router-dom

Tags: node.js, npm, issue-tracking

[PS D:\react\project\my> npm i react-router-dom

up to date, audited 1224 packages in 5s

168 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\react\project\my> npm i latest-version

added 32 packages, removed 21 packages, and audited 1235 packages in 13s

174 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\react\project\my> npm --version
8.3.0
PS D:\react\project\my> npm i react-validation@6.0.0
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for react-validation@6.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wasi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-31T18_14_45_664Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\react\project\my> npm i react-router-dom][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uy85.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using these commands:

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
```

or

```
npm install react-router react-router-dom --save
```